# WPF Scrollviewer PanningMode move Window?

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

I have add a ScrollViewer in my WPF4 Window with ScrollViewer.PanningMode.
When I drag scrollviewer on my multitouch screen it's OK. But... the Window move with scroll when I arrive on top scroll or bottom scroll.
How can we avoid this?

Comment: Does the window move back after the touch is released?

Comment: @HB : Yes exactly. FYI I have tried e.Handled = true on Manipulation*. Doesn't work. And... I don't want to use a SurfaceListBox ;p

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Edit:** To complete the answer: There is a native event for this which can just be marked as handled: [`ManipulationBoundaryFeedback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationboundaryfeedback.aspx)

This movement is called *boundary feedback* which is governed by the operating system (can be set by users in the `Pen and Touch` settings on the `Panning` tab). I do not know if the Windows API allows you to prevent it, [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be relevant.

Comment: Thx HB. I have e.Handled = true ManipulationBoundaryFeedback (scrollview's event) and now all is OK !

Comment: Oh, i didn't know there were native events for that! Glad my answer was of some help in this :)

Comment: One addition: if you want to disable the boundary feedback for all controls in a window, you should put the ManipulationBoundaryFeedback handle on the first panel of the window, not on the window itself.