# Mahapps maximized form

Tags: mahapps.metro

Got a data grid in a maximized Mahapps form. With touch screen, when hold the Data-grid to scroll the Scroll Bar up and down towards Minimum or Maximum. 
Once reach the Minimum/Maximum, the whole form will also be moved up and down slightly, quite annoying. 
Suspect it is due to Scroll Bar hitting Minimum/Maximum effect.
Is there any way to get rid of this effect, and just make the form stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916574/wpf-scrollviewer-panningmode-move-window), it is just something in the Windows API to indicate to the user they have reached the end of the scrollable region.

Handle the `ManipulationBoundaryFeedback` and set e.Handled to true.